# Rendering/extracting .png tiles from metatiles: "Failed to read cmd on fd 4" (OSX)

Tags: macos, apache, mapnik

I am trying to run a tile server using mapnik and mod_tile. For now, I am able to produce metatiles from (zoom,x,y)-requests but I don't understand why tiles are never actually served (as png). The reasons seems to be the following error: **Failed to read cmd on FD 4**

I have checked that metatiles correspond to what I am asking using this tool and everything looks just fine.

Just in case, here is what I have in terms of debug/info:

```
$ sudo -u postgres renderd -f -c /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf
renderd[16811] <Info>: config renderd: unix socketname=/var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
renderd[16811] <Info>: config renderd: num_threads=4
renderd[16811] <Info>: config renderd: num_slaves=0
renderd[16811] <Info>: config renderd: tile_dir=/var/lib/mod_tile
renderd[16811] <Info>: config renderd: stats_file=/var/run/renderd/renderd.stats
renderd[16811] <Info>: config mapnik:  plugins_dir=/usr/local/lib/mapnik/input
renderd[16811] <Info>: config mapnik:  font_dir=/usr/local/lib/mapnik/fonts
renderd[16811] <Info>: config mapnik:  font_dir_recurse=1
renderd[16811] <Info>: config renderd(0): Active
renderd[16811] <Info>: config renderd(0): unix socketname=/var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
renderd[16811] <Info>: config renderd(0): num_threads=4
renderd[16811] <Info>: config renderd(0): tile_dir=/var/lib/mod_tile
renderd[16811] <Info>: config renderd(0): stats_file=/var/run/renderd/renderd.stats
renderd[16811] <Info>: config map 0:   name(default) file(openstreetmap-carto/mapnik.xml) uri(/osm_tiles/) htcp() host(localhost)
renderd[16811] <Info>: Initialising unix server socket on /var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
renderd[16811] <Debug>: Created server socket 3
renderd[16811] <Info>: Renderd is using mapnik version 3.0.13  
...
...
Running in foreground mode...
renderd[16811] <Debug>: Starting stats thread
debug: init_storage_backend: initialising file storage backend at: /var/lib/mod_tile
debug: init_storage_backend: initialising file storage backend at: /var/lib/mod_tile
renderd[16811] <Info>: Loading parameterization function for
debug: init_storage_backend: initialising file storage backend at: /var/lib/mod_tile
debug: init_storage_backend: initialising file storage backend at: /var/lib/mod_tile
renderd[16811] <Info>: Loading parameterization function for
renderd[16811] <Info>: Loading parameterization function for
renderd[16811] <Info>: Loading parameterization function for
Mapnik LOG> 2017-06-10 04:07:37: warning: unable to find face-name 'unifont Medium' in FontSet 'fontset-0'
```

This particular font fails to load, but I'm quite sure its just a duplicate in my mapnik.xml file (it comes with an upper and lower 'u'). The final output after starting the render daemon is (4 times):

```
Jun 10 04:07:39  renderd[16811] <Debug>: Using web Mercator projection settings
```

Then I just clean everything and restart apache:

```
$ rm -rf /var/lib/mod_tile/default/*
$ sudo bash -c 'echo -e "\c" > /var/log/apache2/error-mode_tile.log'
$ sudo apachectl -k restart
```

Finally I try to load a particular tile, say [tile(8,251,160)](http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/8/251/160.png) using my local address: localhost/osm_tiles/8/251/160.png. The render daemon gives the following debug output:

```
renderd[17950] <Debug>: DEBUG: Got incoming connection, fd 4, number 1
renderd[17950] <Debug>: DEBUG: Got incoming request with protocol version 2
renderd[17950] <Debug>: DEBUG: Got command RenderPrio fd(4) xml(default), z(8), x(251), y(160), mime(image/png), options()
renderd[17950] <Debug>: DEBUG: START TILE default 8 248-255 160-167, new metatile
renderd[17950] <Debug>: Rendering projected coordinates 8 248 160 -> 18785164.071375|-6261721.357125 20037508.342800|-5009377.085700 to a 8 x 8 tile
renderd[17950] <Debug>: DEBUG: DONE TILE default 8 248-255 160-167 in 6.177 seconds
debug: Creating and writing a metatile to /var/lib/mod_tile/default/8/0/0/0/250/128.meta
renderd[17950] <Debug>: DEBUG: Sending render cmd(3 default 8/251/160) with protocol version 2 to fd 4
renderd[17950] <Info>: DEBUG: Failed to read cmd on fd 4
renderd[17950] <Debug>: DEBUG: Connection 0, fd 4 closed, now 0 left
```

Here is where the problem appears "Failed to read cmd on fd 4", I tried to look for this online but couldn't find a clear answer to it. Here is the corresponding apache trace:

```
[core:trace5] [pid 18636] protocol.c(643): [client ::1:56548] Request received from client: GET /osm_tiles/8/251/160.png HTTP/1.1
...
[tile:debug] [pid 18636] ./src/mod_tile.c(1306): [client ::1:56548] tile_translate: testing baseuri(/osm_tiles/) name(default) extension(png)
[tile:debug] [pid 18636] ./src/mod_tile.c(1352): [client ::1:56548] tile_translate: request for default was 251 160 256
[tile:debug] [pid 18636] ./src/mod_tile.c(324): [client ::1:56548] get_storage_backend: Retrieving storage back end for tile layer 0 in pool 7fb684031628 and thread -1075362880
[tile:debug] [pid 18636] ./src/mod_tile.c(338): [client ::1:56548] get_storage_backend: No storage backends for this lifecycle 7fb684031628, creating it in thread -1075362880
[tile:debug] [pid 18636] ./src/mod_tile.c(353): [client ::1:56548] get_storage_backend: No storage backend in current lifecycle 7fb684031628 in thread -1075362880 for current tile layer 0
[tile:debug] [pid 18636] ./src/mod_tile.c(1391): [client ::1:56548] tile_translate: op(tile_serve) xml(default) mime(image/png) z(8) x(251) y(160)
[tile:info] [pid 18636] [client ::1:56548] tile_storage_hook: handler(tile_serve), uri(/osm_tiles/8/251/160.png)
[tile:debug] [pid 18636] ./src/mod_tile.c(374): [client ::1:56548] tile_state: determined state of default 251 160 8 on store 7fb683502f90: Tile size: 317572, expired: 0 created: 1497065892
[tile:debug] [pid 18335] ./src/mod_tile.c(176): [client ::1:56547] Connecting to renderd on Unix socket /var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
[tile:info] [pid 18335] [client ::1:56547] Requesting style(default) z(8) x(251) y(160) from renderer with priority 5
[authz_core:debug] [pid 18636] mod_authz_core.c(834): [client ::1:56548] AH01628: authorization result: granted (no directives)
[core:trace3] [pid 18636] request.c(296): [client ::1:56548] request authorized without authentication by access_checker_ex hook: /osm_tiles/8/251/160.png
```

And then it's over, nothing else happens. I really don't know much about this, so any suggestion is welcome. I can also give my config files if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone happen to have the save issue. The problem came from an apple module that is loaded by default by apache (mod_hfs_apple.so). To fix this problem I simply went in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf and commented the following line:
`LoadModule hfs_apple_module libexec/apache2/mod_hfs_apple.so`

This hack is not very satisfactory to me, the goal would be to correct mod_tile. The part that looks to need a fix lies in mod_tile.c:1643:

```
static void register_hooks(__attribute__((unused)) apr_pool_t *p)
{
   ...
   ap_hook_translate_name(tile_translate, NULL, NULL, APR_HOOK_MIDDLE);
   ...
}
```

For now I don't have the courage to find a real solution, just having a quick look I found this strange line that may cause a problem to anyone (eg., mod_hfs_apple) trying to read the request. In mod_tile.c:1278:

```
static int tile_translate(request_rec *r)
{
   ...
               r->filename = NULL; 
   ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The "Failed to read cmd on fd" message isn't actually an error, it's actually just a bit of debug logging.  See the top of https://github.com/openstreetmap/mod_tile/issues/77 for details about the change that introduced it.  If you just want to "not see that message", then the version that I forked from that (for some other changes) https://github.com/SomeoneElseOSM/mod_tile might be useful, as I removed that message there.

However, this won't fix your underlying problem (getting a working tile server) - for that I'd suggest either finding a "soup to nuts" installation guide for MacOS, or to start with so that you can understand how things fit together, a tile server in an Ubuntu VM.

Comment: Telling OP "to get a working tile server, find a guide on the web or use a prebuilt VM" is not an answer.

Comment: Strictly speaking, suggesting the questioner uses https://github.com/SomeoneElseOSM/mod_tile _is_ an answer to the direct question asked here.  What it doesn't do is solve the underlying problem (tile server not rendering tiles) that caused the question about this symptom to be asked.  I've maintained https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-18-04-lts/ for some years no, and experience with people asking about that suggests that "find soup to nuts instructions or use a VM" is the most effective advice.

Comment: Related to that, I looked around for ages for something equivalent for Windows or other OSes before suggesting https://www.openstreetmap.org/user/SomeoneElse/diary/42617 and https://www.openstreetmap.org/user/SomeoneElse/diary/45070 respectively.  If you'd like to contribute a native guide for Macos please do! - head over to https://github.com/switch2osm/switch2osm.github.io and contribute there.